# Show next 10 page numbers per page flask/js

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am having difficulties understanding how to build page numbers.

I want to build page numbers based on my number of array count.

This is my algorithm:

```
var numPages = {{result_arr_count}}/10
```

I want 10 items per page; hence I divide 10 by my total length of array.

```
for(i = 0;i < numPages;i++) {
      var addTwo = i+2;
      var previousPage = arrCount - 10
      var arrCount = addTwo * 10;
      $('#nav').append('<a style="float:center;" class="btn btn-outline-success" href="http://0.0.0.0:5000?page='+arrCount+'&prev='+previousPage+'" >'+pageNum+'</a> ');
```

This gives me the page numbers; but it gives me all the page numbers based on the list count; and it looks really ugly if I have a big array length. IN that case; what I want to do is; per page I want only 10 page numbers shown in total for example

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10 then when they're clicked on 9 show them the next five.. resetting the first five... something like this

[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15] New set of pages but when they click backwards; redisplay them the first five.

I do want to remind that; I do have redirection; so when a user clicks on the page they're redirected to the same page with the new set of data based on 'previousPage' and 'pageNum'.

To display data, I have the flask route setup like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
   result_arr = # this is my result array to show to my users
   current_page_number = # This I pull from the 'page' redirect I mentioned above.
   prev_page_number = #This also I pull from previous page.
   outputArr = []
   for items in result_arr[int(prev_page_number):int(current_page_number)]:
      outputArr.append(items)
  return render_template('.html', arr = outputArr, result_arr_count=len(result_arr))
```

I've shown how I'm getting previous page and current page above.